# Non-root endpoints in cloud run app all go 404

Tags: web, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a flask app deployed in a container on cloud run. All the endpoints work locally and test fine locally.

The root endpoint works perfectly when deployed, but all other endpoints throw a 404 error. This happens both with the cloud run-assigned url and with the mapped url.

Ingress control is set to "all".

This is the only remotely helpful thing in the logs:

```
httpRequest: {
latency: "0.003218553s"
protocol: "HTTP/1.1"
remoteIp: "24.45.214.85"
requestMethod: "GET"
requestSize: "1097"
requestUrl: "https://xxx.xxx.com/routes"
responseSize: "860"
serverIp: "142.251.40.243"
status: 404
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
```

Comment: How are you configuring endpoints? Are you connecting endpoints from Cloud run or outside? Also check with this [Troubleshooting Document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#404).

Comment: endpoints are set up in flask using @app.route decorators!

Comment: Can you share the minimal reproducible steps? Or the Documentation you are following? Also can you try running this command [`gcloud --verbosity=debug endpoints services deploy openapi.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-config-deployment#troubleshooting-other-errors) with the flag to display debug information.